# How to filter nested arrays (composing JS filters)

Tags: javascript, arrays

A am trying to return a new array that is filtered on sub-properties of objects.

I am trying to nest two filters together to achieve this result.

```
let header = "xyz";

let data = [{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    status: "Y"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    status: "N"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    status: "N"
  }]
},{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    status: "N"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    status: "Y"
  }]
}];

let result = data.filter(item => {
  return item.items.filter(item => {
    return item.status === "Y";
  })
});
```

Expected output

```
[{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    status: "Y"
  }]
},{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 2,
    status: "Y"
  }]
}];
```

How can I filter the original array where `status === 'Y'`?

Comment: Yeah, your inner `filter` returns an empty array which is evaluated to true, so nothing gets filtered. Add `.length` to the inner filter or use `.some`.

Comment: `.some` returns `{ id: 1, status: 'Y' }, { id: 1, status: 'N' }, { id: 2, status: 'Y' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce

1. Loop data using reduce
2. Update each object.items before pushing to accumulator-acc of reduce

working code

```js
let header = "xyz";

let data = [{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    status: "Y"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    status: "N"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    status: "N"
  }]
},{
  "header": header,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    status: "N"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    status: "Y"
  }]
}];

console.log(data.reduce((acc,v) => {
  v. items = v.items.filter(item => {
    return item.status === "Y";
  })
  acc.push(v)
   return acc
}, []))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EBXvLx

Answer (score 2):

You could map first to get an equivalent array with filtered sub-items, then filter the main array to remove the elements with no sub-items.

```
let result = data.map(item => {
    return {
        header: item.header,
        items: item.items.filter(subItem => subItem.status === 'Y')
    };
}).filter(item => item.items.length);
```